# Why is rails server trying to load favicon.ico?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, favicon, webrick

As far as I can tell, I'm not referencing favicon.ico in any way shape or form, yet each of my requests to rails server (in development mode) ends with the following:

```
Started GET "/assets/ico/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-12 20:18:02 -0700
Served asset /ico/favicon.ico - 404 Not Found (3ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/ico/favicon.ico"):
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/twler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/twler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/twler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Is this a webrick-related issue, or do I need to change some config options or what?

EDIT: I put favicon.ico in app/assets/ico/favicon.ico, lib/assets/ico/favicon.ico, and public/favicon.ico.  The favicon logo even shows up in my browser, yet rails server still shows a 404 in the log.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not Rails — web browsers request it automatically.

Comment: Did something change recently in Rails or webrick to start showing this?  I have not had it show this before...

Comment: Rails includes one in 'public' by default, which is where browsers request it from by default, but if you have a line in your <head> specifying a different location for it they'll usually listen to that. I wouldn't bother using the pipeline for your favicon, but if you do you would probably need to see which folder Rails routes `.ico` requests to (it might be `images`, but it might also be `icons`; I'm not sure).

Comment: Thanks, I checked the <head> and it had some stuff pasted in for Twitter Bootstrap.  Changed that to the appropriate directory and all is well!

Answer (score 1):

The browser is automatically looking for your site's favicon (the icon you see next to a URL in the address bar and bookmarks). The simplest thing is to create a favicon and save it to /assets/ico/favicon.ico.

Comment: I have tried putting in app/assets/ico/favicon.ico, lib/assets/ico/favicon.ico, and public/favicon.ico.  None of these seem to have any effect.  I just created the favicon here: http://www.favicon.cc/

Comment: @tyler Rails probably doesn't check for anything in `assets/ico/`. Try `assets/images` or `assets/icons`.

Comment: Having the favicon.ico file in the assets directory makes sense... but none of the above locations work for me. Did this get solved by anyone?

Comment: Anyone? Such a silly issue to waste so much time on, but it's wasting mine now.